# Bing maps javascript api license

Tags: bing-maps, bing-api

i have an online ordering website. The users can enter their address in the site.
The address needs to be geocoded and the nearest stores are to be displayed to the user. Basically i need to get the lat and lng of the address entered by user.

Can i use bing maps javascript api for this purpose?

Does this have any licensing issue? I am thinking of a geocoding api which is free.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Bing Maps for this. Since this is a public facing website, this would be licensed using a transactional licensing option. Bing Maps does offer free usage of the service for these types of apps as well. I recommend generating a Bing Maps key to use with the service through Azure: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/partners/bingmaps/mapapis/ This will allow you to move to a paid license if needed very easily and in much smaller increments and prices than what you will normally come across.